# Where can I buy a trusted domain name that I can code in PHP?

Tags: domain

I have been working on a website for a while now, but I was using XAMPP for Windows, and it was only on my computer. Now I am ready to purchase a domain and put it on the web. I can't find a website that is 
- trusted
- popular
- has the tools to code
- secure

I have looked at

- Word Press
- GoDaddy
- 000WebHost
- Domain.com
- Name.com

For example, what domain does Stack Overflow use?

**Edit**

I have my source code on GitHub. Is there any way I can sync it between my GitHub repository and my domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When purchasing a domain name you'll want to use a reputable source. I've always used GoDaddy when doing this professionally.

You're not going to find a domain that is popular that is also available for purchase. It takes a lot of time and effort to increase a domain's SEO and reputation.

Nearly every web server you'll rent/purchase will have either `Apache` or `Nginx` as the http server. These both use `PHP` by default for server-side programming.

I would recommend looking into how to setup your own Apache or Nginx server as you can save a ton of money.

For security, there are too many things to list here, but to start you'll want to look into setting proper file permissions (access control), using files such as `.htaccess` to prevent specific files/directories from being web accessible by anybody. You can get free `ssl/tls` certificates via [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). Maybe most importantly you'll want to learn of to program securely to prevent things like SQL injections.

If you like to really learn how everything works and comes together I'd recommend setting up the server yourself using something like AWS. Installing and configuring an http server like `Apache` or `Nginx` is pretty simple for a simple setup. I also recommend this avenue because it's my understanding that many hosting providers that setup everything for you don't give you root access to the system which can really hinder you ability to optimize the server for your specific needs.

I do these sorts of things professionally, so feel free to ask me for any advice.

Comment: I tried GoDaddy but I can't code it. It is only dragging tools.

Comment: Also, what I meant by popular and purchaseable was that site I use to _buy_ the domain - e.g. GoDaddy. GoDaddy is very reputable, but something like Network solutions or 000webhost have bad reviews or seem sketchy.

Comment: Please see edit to my question

Comment: @Marvin You can 100% add your git source code to your website. That's the entire one of the main points of git or and vcs. You'd want to go to your web root on the server, this is probably `/var/www/html`, then run `git clone <url to repository>`. To get your git repo url go to your repo on github.com and click on the big green button that says "clone or download", copy that url and use it with `git clone <url>`. At his point you can make any changes you need on your local machine, push those changes, then login to your server via ssh and pull those changes down.